# Using conditions in Azure ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is there any way to use conditional statements in templates?

for example I am building template which will have vms with data disks on QA and Production, but no data disks on Dev. Another scenario would be there are some extensions only needs to be installed in prod VMs but no where else.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this is not true, while there is no direct support for conditional logical, similar things can be done using objects and variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key properties to achieve this are:

- `templateLink` that sets the template to be included and the names of the parameters to be passed to the called template.

  ```
  "templateLink": {
      "uri": "[variables('sharedTemplateUrl')]",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
  }
  ```
- `newOrExisting` based on its value we can decide to use an QA versus Productoin config.

  ```
  "newOrExisting": "new",

  "configHash": {
    "new": "[concat(parameters('templateBaseUrl'),'partials/QA.json')]",
    "existing": "[concat(parameters('templateBaseUrl'),'partials/Production.json')]"
  }

  "configTemplate": "[variables('configHash')[parameters('Settings').newOrExisting]]"
  ```

You could see [Azure ARM deployments: how to perform conditional deployments](https://nocentdocent.wordpress.com/2016/02/28/notes-for-azure-arm-how-to-perform-conditional-deployments/) which has provided more details.

Comment: I found one more way using child templates as shown in following example for password authentication type.

 https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/checkpoint-single-nic/azuredeploy.json#L11

Comment: @nitinb obviously it doesn't bother you that there is no nested\child template used in that example...

Comment: This seem to only work for changing between templates dynamically - but what about when you dont want to create a specific resource at all and sometimes you do? Say to enable autoscale in prod but not in test.

Comment: @JimAho, Might be a bit old now, but check out: https://blogs.endjin.com/2016/12/advanced-azure-resource-manager-template-patterns-t-shirt-sizing-and-optional-resources/. "2. Optionally deploying a nested template". Basically, for the "don't do it" option, create a blank template.

Comment: UPDATE: looks like there's a better way: The condition element: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates

Answer (score 10):

You can leverage the newly released comparison functions to accomplish most of this.

Here is an example of how you would use a parameter to determine if a storage account should be deployed.

Parameter:

```
"deployStorage": {
  "type": "string"
},
```

Resource:

```
{
  "condition": "[equals(parameters('deployStorage'),'yes')]",
  "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
  },
  "kind": "Storage"
}
```

Notice the new condition property in the resource along with the most recent API version for the storage provider.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-comparison

Comment: I am using condition element in my templates and I expect it to not expect storageAccountName if the parameter "deployStorage" is not set to "yes". However, it errors out with following   InvalidTemplate
Deployment template validation failed: 'The value for the template parameter 'name' at line '166' and column '39' is not provided.' Is the condition element is the correct choice here if I want Azure to not ask for resource parameter when the deployStorage is set to "no" ?