# Resource Template - Count array items on condition

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to count the number of items in an array based upon a certain condition in Resource Templates? Similar to how we can use 'Where-Object' within PowerShell. Seems that the 'length' function is only able to count the total number of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that, unless you hack your way through using nested templates. And that is only possible if you want to compare against a specific object, and you would probably need at least 2 levels of indirection.

And i would generally advice against that, unless there's no other option.

but if you want to do that, you would need [this function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-comparison#equals), nested deployments and [ARM template way of doing conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899613/using-conditions-in-azure-arm-templates) and I would argue that you would need a state parameter in the nested templates to share the state between those.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is pretty much old and is outdated.
The ARM template function `length(arg1)`returns the number of elements in an array, characters in a string, or root-level properties in an object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-array#length